# Reading a .txt file into a char array and printing it

Tags: c++, arrays, file, io

I am trying to read in a file and print it.  The .txt file is the maze I am trying to print, and so I am putting it in a 2d char array first. But as you can see when I print the output it is getting screwed up somehow.  What is going on???

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void beginGame();

int main(){
    beginGame();
    return 0;
}

void beginGame(){
    char map[20][30];

    //read a .txt file into the program
    ifstream file;
    file.open("FloorA.txt");
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++){
                file.get(c);
                map[i][j] = c;
        }
    }
    file.close();

    //print the array
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 30; j++){
            cout << map[i][j];
        }
        cout << "." << endl;
    }
}
```

FloorA.txt

```
##############################
#      K                     #
#  ############## ### ###  # #
#      K    #   # #C# #K#  # #
# ######### # A # # # # #  # #
#      K    #   #          # #
# ############D#####D####### #
#                            #
#   C         G        C     #
#                            #
# ######D##############D#### #
#      #  C         #K#    # #
# #### ######## #   # #      #
# #K   #      # ### # # #### #
# # ## # #### #   # # #    # #
E # ## # #    ### # # #### # #
# #    # #K           D    # #
# #D#### ################### #
#                    K       #
##############################
```

Output:

```
##############################.
#      K                     .
#  ############## ### ###  #.
#      K    #   # #C# #K#  .
# ######### # A # # # # # .
#      K    #   #        .
# ############D#####D###.
#                      .
#   C         G       .
#                    .
# ######D###########.
#      #  C        .
# #### ######## # .
# #K   #      # #.
# # ## # #### # .
E # ## # #    #.
# #    # #K   .
# #D#### ####. #
#           .## #
###########.     #
```

Comment: Try 31 instead of 30 for linefeed character (in text read mode)

Answer (score 0):

FloorA.txt has 30 characters plus the newline, which makes a total of 31 per row.  You could change the array to be map[20][31] and loop through j < 31 in the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

The actual output is

```
##############################.

#      K                     .
#
#  ############## ### ###  #.
 #
#      K    #   # #C# #K#  .
# #
# ######### # A # # # # # .
 # #
#      K    #   #        .
  # #
# ############D#####D###.
#### #
#                      .
      #
#   C         G       .
 C     #
#                    .
        #
# ######D###########.
###D#### #
#      #  C        .
 #K#    # #
# #### ######## # .
  # #      #
# #K   #      # #.
## # # #### #
# # ## # #### # .
  # # #    # #
E # ## # #    #.
## # # #### # #
# #    # #K   .
        D    # #
# #D#### ####.
############### #
#           .
         K       #
###########.
```

The out-of-place new-lines should give you a clue - each line of `FloorA.txt` has `30` characters followed by a newline. `get` does not ignore newlines. Thus, while `map[0][0]` to `map[0][29]` have the desired values, the `31`st character read, a newline, will be written into `map[1][0]`. This explains the rest of the output as well. To fix this, just read the newline separately.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++){
                file.get(c);
                map[i][j] = c;
        }
        file.get(c);//To read the newline
    }
```